# Regex to capture time

Tags: regex

Hi I have a **Time** field which contains data like this:

```
----------
   Time
----------
   12pm
   3pm
   11:45pm
   1pm
   11am
   4:30pm
   10:30am
```

I wrote Regex like this but it does not work:

```
^\d*\d:\d{2} .M$,h:mm aa,HHmm
```

What regex can cover all the value I have in Time field?

Comment: "_it does not work_" How not?

Comment: [`\d+(:\d{2})?[ap]m$`](https://regex101.com/r/pwUrCU/1)

Comment: Thanks @SeanBright. Your answer is correct too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match a digit 1 to 12 and make the :minutes part optional using an optional non capturing group:

```
^(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?[ap]m$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `1[0-2]` match 10, 11 or 12
  - `|` Or
  - `0?[1-9]` Match optional 0 and a digit 1-9
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `:[0-5][0-9]` Match the minutes part from 00 to 59
- `)?` Close on capturing group and make it optional
- `[ap]m` Match am or pm
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jCvGpH/1)

Comment: Thank alot @The fourth bird

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
(?<TimePart>(?<Hour>\d|\d{2}):(?<Minute>\d{2})|(?<Hour>\d|\d{2}))(?<DayPart>am|pm)
```

It looks to match the full time (hours and minutes) or just hours and then matches the am or pm.